# Why get error from kendo ui when run the asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc use the kendo UI and add it to my project but when i run the my application get this error:
[image]

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is saying, the `kendo` assemblies are using MVC version `5.2.3.0` where as your MVC version is `5.2.2.0`.

Please update your MVC version to match that of kendo. You may update it using nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/